# div layout problems in IE ...

Tags: internet-explorer, layout, html

I have developed a website http://www.akademikpencere.com/.
The problem is some divs elements are not being posistioned well in IE, but they are positioned well in Firefox and Chrome.
How to solve this problem ?
Is there any way to make sure what ever I develop for one browser will work for another ?
thank you.

Comment: For those of us without IE, can you show a picture of the problem and give a description?

Comment: Sorry, no way to make sure. Someone has to physically look at each page to see if everything's lining up. That someone is usually (hopefully?) you.  Or try this: http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 2):

For IE, you can use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and include your CSS that targets IE only; for the rest of the standard-compliant browsers, the main CSS file should be used. This way, you can use a different stylesheet for IE and fix your problem.

You may also try putting [Eric Meyer Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) into your main stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `float:right` CSS applied to the `DIV`s on the side of your `content_one_sag` area.  It looks as though you have a fixed-width system applied (336+10+10 px) and something in IE is causing the DIVs to break to the next line.

As a quick fix, I'd suggest widening the parent by a pixel or four. Or, narrowing the children by a pixel or four.

Also, you could experiment with `clear:both` to remove floats when necessary from DIVs (maybe apply to `giris_submit`).

Comment: it didnot work for me. Why the website in firefox is displayed nicely but in IE so big. Very interesting.

Comment: At last I solved the problem. First of all I validatwed my website with W3 validator and rectified all the errors I received. And everything started working properly.